# Accessing variables within a method dynamically? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
class A(object):

    def setup(self):

        self.array1 = [1,2,3]
        self.array2 = [4,5,6]
        self.array3 = [7,8,9]

    def function(self):

        for i in range(1,4):

            for j in range(3):

                #code goes here
                #code goes here
```

Now here's the important bit: Is there a way to easily access an index of a dynamically called up array, such as `arrayi[j]` and be able to easily store it/pass it as a parameter into a function in one line? I am aware that one can use `setattr(A, "array", "temp")` to store the array into a temporary variable and then access a list index from that, but is there a easier way to do it?

Comment: In your `setup`, do you mean `self.array1 = ...` etc. ? Otherwise you're just creating local variables that won't be available later.

Comment: You can make a list of lists. So instead of doing `arrayi[j]` (which is not possible by the way), you can just do `array[i][j]`.

Comment: @khelwood Yeah, forgot that.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin So it's not possible, gotcha. Stupid question, good answer.

Comment: Both answers are virtually the same, but giving the points to diz as he answered first. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should try to use list of lists? Something like this:

```
class A(object):

def setup(self):
    self.array = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ]

def function(self):

    for i in range(3):

        for j in range(3):

            # self.array[i][j]
```

Comment: Completely forgot that. The list's size and complexity in my program just made multiple lists seem fine. But is there a method of achieving what I want, assuming that list of lists are not viable?

Comment: @Dova you could dynamically create attribute name as a string and use `getattr(self, array_name)` where `array_name = 'array{}'.format(i)`

Comment: but that is really ugly method

Answer (score 1):

More Pythonic way:

```
class A(object):

    def setup(self):
        self.array = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]
        ]

    def func(self):
        for subl in self.array:
            for num in subl:
                # code here
```